# Android Studio - change default code style

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm used to write code in a such way:

```
private String blabla()
{
    return "bla";
}
```

But Android Studio is adjusted for this code:

```
private String blabla() {
    return "bla";
    }
```

Question: how can I change this option for me?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Go to File -> Settings.

Then in dialog, Editor -> Code Style -> Java -> Wrapping and Braces tab, then you can adjust `braces placement`

Remember to "Apply" your changes.

Answer (score 1):

After change settings, You might formatted yours files through CTRL+ALT+L

Answer (score 1):

**In Android Studio 4.**

**File > Settings > Editor > Code Style > "Select the programing languae"** > set Line length: 300. for example

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8TW3.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is correct.
However, it seems the path may have changed just a little bit, I am using Android Studio version 3.3.2 for Windows.

The path is: File > Settings (Ctrl + Alt + S) > Editor > Code Style > Java.

Then select your relevant tab. In this case is was the Wrapping and Braces tab. I wanted to set some naming conventions the other day so I selected the Code Generation tab.